# Cancel the requestAnimationFrame loop after some time

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, requestanimationframe, cancelanimationframe

I want to cancel an animation after a timeout. Here's my code

```
function animate(){
        id = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        console.log(id);
        c.clearRect(0,0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        for(let i = 0; i < circleArray.length; i++){
            circleArray[i].scatter();
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
            id = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            cancelAnimationFrame(id);
            update();
        },5000)
    }
    
    function update(){
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
        c.clearRect(0,0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        for(let i = 0; i < circleArray.length; i++){
            circleArray[i].update();
        }
    }
```

Here, I want to stop the recursion of the animate function and start the update function. But the animate doesnt stop and update function runs concurrently after the given time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a variable to reference the current render function and change that variable on the timer event.

Example

```
var currentFrameRender = animate;  // set current render
requestAnimationFrame(currentFrameRender); // request first frame
setTimeout(() => currentFrameRender = update ,5000); // switch render in 5s
setTimeout(() => currentFrameRender = undefined ,10000); // stop animation in 10s

function animate(){
    c.clearRect(0, 0, c.canvas.width, c.canvas.height);
    for(let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++){
        circleArray[i].scatter();
    }

    // request frame only if currentFrameRender is defined
    currentFrameRender && requestAnimationFrame(currentFrameRender);
}

function update(){
    c.clearRect(0, 0, c.canvas.width, c.canvas.height);
    for(let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++){
        circleArray[i].update();
    }

    // request frame only if currentFrameRender is defined
    currentFrameRender && requestAnimationFrame(currentFrameRender);
}
```